# Dialog file to update list rows does not work / OnItemLongClick

Tags: android, jquery, onlongclicklistener

I managed to get Dialog to show up on the long click by implementing this code:

```
ListView list = getListView();
        list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    new EditListItemDialog(view.getContext()).show();

                return true;       
            }
        });
```

Unfortunately, when the dialog opens and prompts for new text input, when clicked ok, no changes are made to the list. 
Here is the Dialog file:

```
package com.example.classorganizer;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

class EditListItemDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {

private View editText;

public EditListItemDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_text_dialog);//here is your xml with EditText and 'Ok' and 'Cancel' buttons
    View btnOk = findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
    editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    btnOk.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ((TextView) editText).getText().toString();//here is your updated(or not updated) text
    dismiss();
}
```

}

Here is the file containing list:

```
package com.example.classorganizer;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.cookbook.data.Constants;
import com.cookbook.data.MyDB;




public class Monday extends ListActivity {



private static final int MyMenu = 0;
MyDB dba;
DiaryAdapter myAdapter;

private class MyDiary{
    public MyDiary(String t, String c){
        title=t;
        content=c;

        ListView list = getListView();
        list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    new EditListItemDialog(view.getContext()).show();

                return true;       
            }
        });

}

    public String title;
    public String content;

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    dba = new MyDB(this);
    dba.open();
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_monday);





    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myAdapter = new DiaryAdapter(this);
    this.setListAdapter(myAdapter);
}



private class DiaryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<MyDiary> fragment_monday;
    public DiaryAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        fragment_monday = new ArrayList<MyDiary>();
        getdata();


    }

    public void getdata(){
        Cursor c = dba.getdiaries();
        startManagingCursor(c);
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                String title =
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.TITLE_NAME));
                String content =
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.CONTENT_NAME));

                MyDiary temp = new MyDiary(title,content);
                fragment_monday.add(temp);
            } while(c.moveToNext());
        }

    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {return fragment_monday.size();}
    public MyDiary getItem(int i) {return fragment_monday.get(i);}
    public long getItemId(int i) {return i;}
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        View v = arg1;
        if ((v == null) || (v.getTag() == null)) {
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.diaryrow,  null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mTitle = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.name);

            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        holder.mdiary = getItem(arg0);
        holder.mTitle.setText(holder.mdiary.title);


        v.setTag(holder);

        return v;


    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        MyDiary mdiary;
        TextView mTitle;


    }

}




/** Called when the user clicks the Edit button */
public void visitDiary(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Diary.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
/** Called when the user clicks the back button */
public void visitSchedule(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayScheduleScreen.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}


}
```

Here is an xml file for dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_ok"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OK" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I don't understand why the rows are not being updated with data entered through Dialog file...

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ((TextView) editText).getText().toString();//here is your updated(or not updated) text
    dismiss();
}
```

You are getting the value from TextView of the dialog ,have u added the data to the list.

Update the data to the list

```
fragment_monday.add(((TextView) editText).getText().toString());
```

Comment: when I update this by adding fragment_monday I get error that it cannot be resolved...

Comment: your answer sounds reasonable but i am getting error while adding fragment_monday

Comment: I just given to you a hint(Not i mention exact fragment_monday). You have to analyze the which list are going to be add the entered data.  Then you may fix the problem.

Comment: it was a good hint! but I am not sure whether I don't have to declare fragment_monday in other place in code in order for it to work. Now App crashes when in Dialog I click ok to append data changes to the table. Guys say that this is due to null value of fragment_monday which is the xml for my list view